# Can someone resend a digitally signed email

Tags: email, digital-signature

If someone receives a copy of a digitally signed email, is there any way they can resend from their own account so that it still appears to be digitally signed by the original sender.  i.e. if they resend an exact binary copy of the email will that appear to be signed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since it still was digitally signed by the original sender, it will still appear to be signed by the original sender. It works the same way with physical signatures -- I can take a letter signed by someone else and mail it to you. The letter will still appear to be signed by the same person. I just can't tamper with the contents of the letter.

If this was not so, how could servers deliver the signed email to you? All they receive is a copy of the digitally signed email. And it's not like they have some account of their own that they can send them from. The resend an exact digital copy, and of course it still appears to be signed since it still is signed since digital copies are not distinguishable from originals.

> ... resend from their own account so that it still appears to be digitally signed by the original sender ...

Note that since the email will, as you said, still appear to have been signed by the original sender, and it was in fact signed by the original sender, there's no vulnerability or issue here.

Comment: Thanks, my concern is with the email "Approved" being able to be resent and appearing to be signed.

Comment: Why would that be a problem? Presumably, you want the email to be delivered to the recipient and you want it to appear to have been signed by you. Why does it matter by what method it gets there? The contents can't be tampered with without invalidating the signature. (You shouldn't just send any messaged signed without enough context to make it clear what you're signing. It's the same way with paper signatures. You wouldn't sign a piece of paper that says "I approve your suggestion".)

Comment: "You shouldn't just send any messaged signed without enough context to make it clear what you're signing.". That's exactly the point, I was considering a process where only "Approved" would be acceptable, clearly thats no good, Thanks.

Comment: Correct. No sane person would ever sign a message that read only "Approved"! On the bright side, the recipient (usually) and date (almost always) are typically included in the signed content. So that's something.

Comment: > "the recipient (usually) and date (almost always) are typically included in the signed content.", but easy to miss.

Comment: Yeah. You need to think about signing an email, if you use email signatures for some specific purpose, the same as you think about signing a piece of paper.